# Maximally-self-managed hosting-platforms and OS-and-above containerizators (like Vagrant)

Tags: containers, automation, configuration-management, vagrant, servers

A maximally-self-managed hosting-platform like DigitalOcean/Linode lets a customer quickly create its own VPSE (Virtual Private Server Environment) which includes a common [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foss) operating system like Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS and so forth.

Besides that, the FOSS community offers a type of software that I can call *OS-and-above containerizator* (like *Vagrant*).

I'm wondering if maximally-self-managed hosting-platforms that gives an operating system to choose and work with makes software like Vagrant totally redundant in case one desires continuous integration.

For example, people who like continuous integration might take this path:

1. Spin up ubuntu/bionic64 box with Vagrant
2. Provision it with Ansible playbook that installs Docker 18.06.1-ce
3. Start Docker container based on mysql:5.7.24 image

Given such circumstances, wouldn't maximally-self-managed hosting-platforms redund the first step thus making software like Vagrant useless in such services?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to DevOps... questions like these help us explore the nature of the DevOps environment, but unfortunately are a bad fit for a StackExchange site. This question is impossible to answer definitively and objectively, so you're at risk of being voted down or flagged. Can you please try to narrow down the thing you're asking? As it stands, the answer is "yes, of course they do, but also no, because people have diverse needs"

Comment: Hello @BruceBecker ! Can you help me here a bit? I don't know how it's best to narrow down this question... Do you have any suggestion?... I'll gladly make a change...

Comment: Sure! What is the _key_ question you want answered? IE, what _difference_ are you trying to make to your current state of affairs? E.g. you may want to know whether *you* should forego Vagrant and use Digital Ocean for continuous integration. This implies a specific case that you have in mind and specific criteria that you have set. Try to nail these down and edit the question. Hope that helps :)

Comment: FYI vagrant has a digitalocean driver, as well as an ec2 and vsphere one among others, defining your machines as code is as much important as their configuration when you don't want to have to click thousands times to create a new environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are plenty of providers which make the first step redundant; i.e. they give you a working, optimized, running Linux box just by clicking a button, without you having to care how it works. Or they skip the need to have a "box" (VM) running at all. AWS, Azure, GCP, OpenShift etc. all do that, and do it well.

In my neck of the woods, we use Vagrant primarily to get developers up to speed quickly; i.e. to install them a VM which has just the right ingredients needed for development of a specific application (a specific version of whatever compiler, OS packages etc. are needed). This works well because Vagrant leaves the dev with a bog-standard VM, which he can either keep permanently, owning it (e.g., modifying it to set up their preferred editor/IDE right inside, and so on), or for having a throw-away.

Frankly, when we need to spin up many things, Vagrant (or rather: VMs) is just a bit too heavy. We use containers for that; and Kubernetes (and the cloud providers as mentioned) deliver a *much* higher integration than Vagrant, in any case.